# Why file path is invalid in a MQ configurable service?

Tags: mq, messagebroker

I have a configurable service (CDServer). When I try to deploy my WMB flow that uses a CDInput Node, which is using the configurable service I got the following error:

```
BIP7962E: File path '\\192.168.45.91\myfolder' specified for the property 'brokerPathToInputDir' in the CDServer configurable service is not valid.
```

The file path is accesible from my Windows Explorer. The folder "myfolder" is shared on the remote computer.

I don't know where could be the error. I've tried chanching the file path to a different format (192.168.45.91\myfolder), but still doesn´t work.

I'm using:

WMB 8.0.0.1
MQ 7
Sterling Connect Direct 4.6

Any help on this issue is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm up against the same problem.  While I continue to hope for a solution that works like yours, my manager told me yesterday he had wrestled with the problem a year ago, and the only solution he found was to put an SFTP server in the middle.  For his message flow, he used Attachmate Reflection.

The FileInput node has hooks for remote access.  On the FTP tab, click Remote Transfer and fill in the Attachmate server and port, and other settings.  Attachmate in turn is configured with a virtual folder, which accesses the actual remote server.

It seems like more machinery than is necessary, but you can't argue with the fact that it works and has been in production for over a year.

Comment: Don, thank you for the answer! Very interesting solution. I'm going to try this approach. On [MQSeries.net](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=63311) they gave me a clue on where the error might be.